# Osculating circle and its relation with level site

Tags: multivariable-calculus, osculating-circle

Find the osculating circle $C$ of the parabola $x^2+y=0$ at the origin $(0,0)$. Find a function $f(x,y)$ such that $C$ is a level curve of $f$.

What I have done so far was to find the quadratic equation for osculating circle. However, I did not understand how that equation correlates with level curve. If remember correctly, level curve meant to be $f(x,y)$ being a constant number.

Comment: If you have a circle centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, it is by definition a level set of $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by that equation?

Comment: Not sure how else to elaborate...a circle centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ is a level set of $f(x,y)=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$, namely it is the graph of the equation $f(x,y)=r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle. So you need to find the radius of the circle (the reciprocal of the absolute value of the curvature) as well as the center. To find the center, it suffices to move from $(0,0)$ to the center along the inward normal vector a distance equal to the radius of curvature...or you can just use the formulas at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html

Comment: Wait, I have everything related to the equation of circle. What I need is how to associate the level curve of $f$ with that equation. And now, as I read through your comments, I try to understand that equation itself is level curve and we should just write it in the form as you suggested right?!
In that case, everything has become clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, a circle is a level curve of the function that maps a point to its distance to a particular point, or to any function of that distance that you like (I used the square of the distance).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said any *one-to-one* function of the distance. Note that $x \mapsto x^2$ is one-to-one on $[0,\infty)$.